# FTDI chip USB to serial converter sending bytes over RX

Tags: c++, uart, serial-communication, ftdi

I'm programming a serial communication for a microcontroller, and using UART for this. To connect to UART I'm using a USB to serial Converter which include a FTDI chip. The issue is that the TX **and RX** are sending bytes (tested with Salea Logic). How is this possible? For sending bytes I used WriteFile, as it's described in MSDN.

Thanks for helping!

```
char bytes_to_send[5];
bytes_to_send[0] = 0x48;
bytes_to_send[1] = 31;
bytes_to_send[2] = 31;
bytes_to_send[3] = 31;
bytes_to_send[4] = 13;

HANDLE hComm;
hComm = CreateFile(L"COM4", GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0);

if (hComm == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
    std::cout << "error\n";
}
else {
    std::cout << "connected \n";

    DCB dcbParams = { 0 };

    dcbParams.BaudRate = CBR_115200;
    dcbParams.ByteSize = 8;
    dcbParams.fParity = NOPARITY;
    dcbParams.StopBits = ONESTOPBIT;
    dcbParams.fDtrControl = DTR_CONTROL_ENABLE;
    if (!SetCommState(hComm, &dcbParams))
    {
        printf("ALERT: Could not set Serial Port parameters");
    }
    else
    {
        
        //Flush any remaining characters in the buffers 
        PurgeComm(hComm, PURGE_RXCLEAR | PURGE_TXCLEAR);
        //We wait 2s as the Arduino board will be resetting
        Sleep(4000);
        std::cout << "everything is ok... \n";


        DWORD bytes_written, total_bytes_written = 0;
        fprintf(stderr, "Sending bytes...");
        if (!WriteFile(hComm, bytes_to_send, 5, &bytes_written, NULL))
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error\n");
            CloseHandle(hComm);
            return 1;
        }
        std::cout << "all bytes sent" << std::endl;

        //Flush any remaining characters in the buffers 
        PurgeComm(hComm, PURGE_RXCLEAR | PURGE_TXCLEAR);
        char buffer[255];
        DWORD bytesRead;

        /*while (int i=ReadFile(hComm, buffer, 1, &bytesRead, NULL)) {
            std::cout << "Bytes read" + (char)i << std::endl;
            std::cout << buffer << std::endl;
        }*/



    }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean with "*TX and RX are sending bytes*"? What was the problem? Please use the terminology consistently e.g. sending (**TX**: PC-->micro-controller), receiving (**RX**: PC <-- micro-controller) then refine the question.

Comment: Solve the problem, chip was broken!